# How to untarget an application in Weblogic server using weblogic.Deployer Command-Line Reference?

Tags: deployment, weblogic

How to untarget a deployed application from a managed server in Weblogic server using weblogic.Deployer Command-Line Reference.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, 
to **Deploy**, we use

> weblogic.Deployer

as in the following link :
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/DEPGD/wldeployer.htm#DEPGD333

Syntax:

```
$ java [SSL Arguments] weblogic.Deployer 
     Connection Arguments [User Credentials Arguments] 
     -deploy [[-name] deployment_name] [-source] file 
     [-plan file] [-targets target_list] [-submoduletargets target_list] 
     [-upload]
     [-stage | -nostage | -external_stage]
     [-planstage | -plannostage | -planexternal_stage]
     [-retiretimeout seconds]
     [-library [-libspecver version] [-libimplver version]]
     [-altappdd file] [-altwlsappdd file]
     [-securityModel] [-enableSecurityValidation] 
     [-id task_id]
     [Common Arguments]
```

The following command starts a deployment operation and specifies the task identifier, myDeployment:

```
$ java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:7001 
     -username weblogic -password weblogic 
     -deploy ./myapp.ear -id myDeployment
```

If the deployment task has not yet completed, the following command attempts to cancel the deployment operation:

```
$ java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:7001 
     -username weblogic -password weblogic 
     -cancel -id myDeployment
```

Like *Deploying*, we use

> weblogic.Deployer

to **Undeploy**

```
$ java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user weblogic
   -password weblogic -name mymodule -undeploy -graceful
```

> Note: Using the -undeploy command without the -targets and
>   -submoduletargets flags completely removes the application or stand-alone module from all WebLogic Server instances and untargets
>   all JMS sub-module resources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i tried the command "java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user weblogic
   -password weblogic -name mymodule -undeploy -graceful". It undeployed the application from weblogic server. But I just need to untarget the application from weblogic server instances instead undeploying it. 
Untarget makes the application status from "Active" to "Installed" in weblogic console.

Comment: @AJK but did you see the ending of the below "Note: Using the -undeploy command without the -targets . . .  `untargets` all JMS sub-module resources"?

Comment: Ok but how does it help for my requirement?

Comment: @AJK you may manage `untargetting` by "using `undeploy` without the -targets and -submoduletargets flags"

Comment: Actually untarget of EAR from weblogic server instance is required before undeploying shared lib which is referred by that EAR. But I didnt find any command for it. So,  I used "stop" and "start" commands on EAR file before undeploying and deploying its shared lib.